# Excel: [pics added] Change cells with specific values based on drop down list

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I can not figure this out. 
I have a list of games (game1, game2, etc.) and within those games a list of two teams that played in them. (teamA, teamB, etc.)
I have a drop down menu next to those listed teams that has two values (won, lost).

Then I have a separate list of people that are choosing who they think will win. Next to their names are their guesses under a column labeled for each game.

[image: Example of table]

I want to be able to change the drop down menu next to each team to win or lost and I'd like all the cells with that teams name in them to change to green or red respectively based on that drop down value.

[image: Example of results]

So how can I change multiple cells with a specific value based on a drop down list not containing that value.

OR

How can I change cells that contain the value of a drop down list. 
So if I had a column that said Game1 and I selected from a list the team that won, say TeamA. How can I look through the sheet and change all sells that say TeamA to background color green?

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Any chances you could add screenshots of the setup of your lists of games, people, etc. Currently its hard to read and understand the problem statement as is

Comment: please show example, not sure why simple conditional formatting wouldn't work?

Comment: Hi guys/gals - I suggested an edit on this post with some screenshots of how the two lists would look like. The only way to share pics was to edit the question instead of putting those in the comments. But unfortunately the diligent editors of our wonderful SO community have chosen to reject my edit 2 to 1 (@Nimeshka Srimal, @mbuechmann and @Paddy). Is there a way that I could share my screenshots to help the asker of this question out, given that I have spent time to re-create the problem? Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: @BharatAnand I have added some images as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its doable.

So you will have 8 combinations you will have to add manually in the Conditional Formatting. Select Cell `C3:C7` (which range the conditional formula should be applied to) and the go to "Conditional Formatting" -> "Use a formula to determine which cells to format".

Enter the formula:

```
=IF(C3="teamA";$H$3="win")
```

So this will make all "teamA" cells green in the range `C3:C7`, if result: "win" are choosen in cell `H3`.

[image]

All 8 combinations that should be applied are listed below:

```
=IF(C3="teamA";$H$3="win") --- Applies to range: =$C$3:$C$7 (is showed above as an example)
=IF(C3="teamA";$H$3="lost") --- Applies to range: =$C$3:$C$7

=IF(C3="teamB";$H$4="win") --- Applies to range: =$C$3:$C$7
=IF(C3="teamB";$H$4="lost") --- Applies to range: =$C$3:$C$7

=IF(D3="teamC";$H$6="win") --- Applies to range: =$D$3:$D$7
=IF(D3="teamC";$H$6="lost") --- Applies to range: =$D$3:$D$7

=IF(D3="teamD";$H$7="win") --- Applies to range: =$D$3:$D$7
=IF(D3="teamD";$H$7="lost") --- Applies to range: =$D$3:$D$7
```

[image]

Your final result should then be:

[image]

Please notice I use a Nordic version of excel so you might change the delimiter from "`;`" to "`,`".

```
Nordic: ";"  - =IF(C3="teamA";$H$3="win")
US: ","      - =IF(C3="teamA",$H$3="win")
```

Comment: hello, I did not understand the use of ";" in your conditions inside the IF formula. Is it some kind of AND operator. I even tried entering into an excel cell and get the error message indicating **There's a problem with this formula**

Comment: Hi @BharatAnand, Sorry for the inconvenience, I should have explained :). It's my delimiter in Excel. You should replace all "`;`" -> "`,`". I use a Nordic version where the delimiter is "`;`" as default regional configurations. Switch to "`,`" and it should work for you!! I have also updated the post to reflect this!

Comment: thanks, this was not so hard, should have occurred to me earlier!

Comment: ;), take care :)!